# Is it safe to force QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb on Linux Desktop?

Tags: qt, gnome, xcb, wayland

I recently found that our Qt application uses "own" window frame instead of the system frame on Ubuntu 21.10. As a result, the look is weird, especially in the dark theme.

The investigation shown that is a known Qt+Gnome+Wayland issue. It can be easily fixed if I run the app with `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb`.

So my question is, is it safe to just set `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` to `xcb` in the application start script for *all* users. Do I have to expect some issues if I do so? If yes, what kind of issues?

Comment: No idea about the direct question but you could force a few window modes including the one you want with https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum with `setWindowFlags` call.